# Combining list to a list of lists, where matches are in same list inside the list

Tags: python, list, object

I have two lists, and I want to combine them into a list where the object in the list is a list of matches between the two lists, but also include objects that do not match.

I am a bit lost on where to even start to get this result as I am a python novice.

The two lists:

```py
husband = ['cat','dog','bunny']
wife = ['dog','bunny','horse']
```

The result I want:

```py
farm = [['cat'],['dog','dog'],['bunny','bunny'],['horse']]
```

Comment: Are those lists of strings "cat" or lists of objects?

Comment: Do you have an algorithm for this and have trouble coding it in Python, or do you not have an algorithm? Then this is not a Python problem.

Comment: I think a better data structure for your "farm" would be a `Counter()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
full_l = husband + wife
unique_l = list(dict.fromkeys(full_l))
# unique list with order preserved,  if you dont want to preserve order, you can just use set(full_l)
output = [[animal] * full_l.count(animal) for animal in unique_l]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sets

```
In [25]: husband = ["cat","dog","bunny"]
    ...: wife = ["dog","bunny","horse"]

In [26]: husband_set = set(husband)

In [27]: wife_set = set(wife)

In [28]: data = []

In [29]: data.extend([[i] * 2 for i in wife_set.intersection(husband_set)])

In [30]: data.append([i for i in husband_set.difference(wife_set)])

In [31]: data.append([i for i in wife_set.difference(husband_set)])

In [32]: data
Out[32]: [['dog', 'dog'], ['bunny', 'bunny'], ['cat'], ['horse']]
```

Comment: Are there prizes for "Using only sets"? ;) Anyway, you use lists also

Comment: Haha, changed to `using sets`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here are couple of way's using `collections` module,

```
from collections import Counter,defaultdict

husband = ['cat','dog','bunny']
wife = ['dog','bunny','horse']

print([[k] * v for k , v in Counter(husband + wife).items()])

#or

farm = defaultdict(list)
for v in husband + wife:
    farm[v].append(v)

print(farm.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can use the `collections` module:

```
from collections import Counter

husband = ['cat','dog','bunny']
wife = ['dog','bunny','horse']

farm = Counter(husband+wife) # Counter({'dog': 2, 'bunny': 2, 'cat': 1, 'horse': 1})
farm = [[k]*farm[k] for k in farm]

print(farm)
```

Output:

```
[['cat'], ['dog', 'dog'], ['bunny', 'bunny'], ['horse']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem for `groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

husband = ['cat', 'dog', 'bunny']
wife = ['dog', 'bunny', 'horse']

farm = [list(group) for _, group in groupby(sorted(husband + wife))]

print(farm)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
% python3 test.py
[['bunny', 'bunny'], ['cat'], ['dog', 'dog'], ['horse']]
%
```